# How to force Chrome to use HTTP/1.1 for a particular Website?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, http2, http-error, firefox-developer-tools, http-1.1

Whenever I am visiting a particular website via same chrome version on 2 different windows machine the protocol in network tab is showing different protocol versions.
Here, I can not post the website details because of business confidentiality.

However, the case is not the same with other websites.

Note: I have not configured any proxies on any system. I do not use any vpn.
Both systems are running on windows 10, latest chrome version as of 22-10-2023.

Can anyone tell me how to use http/1.1 forcefully for the particular website (Let's say x) on chrome? I am asking because the systems that are showing http/2 are having some glitches while rendering the content in some cases. example- in few particular pages upon clicking a button the following result is shown in network status tab **net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR**.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBRfN.jpg)[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQBlH.png)

I tried solving the issue by disabling/enabling the quic protocol option in chrome://flags.
I also tried to disable HTTP/2 by editing registry in windows by reading an article on web.
Nothing works by the way.  I do not want to re-configure anything from the application level. I just want google chrome to use http/1.1 forcefully for the particular website on the other system.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you informed the developers of that service so they can fix it?